# Relation of Cox-de Boor recursion and convolution (B-spline basis)

Tags: polynomials, convolution, recursion, spline

Consider the Cox-de Boor recursion formula for producing B-spline basis functions given a knot vector:

$N_{i,0}(u)=1    $  if $u_i\leq u <  u_{i+1}$
otherwise,  $=0$

$N_{i,p}(u)=\frac{u-u_{i}}{u_{i+p}-u_{i}}N_{i,p-1}(u)+
 \frac{u_{i+p+1}-u}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}}N_{i+1,p-1}(u)$

Now, I read that B-splines can also be produced using recursive convolution instead of the recursion formula above. For example, see this page: http://www.chebfun.org/examples/approx/BSplineConv.html

Can someone explain if these two are related in any way, I am just not seeing it? And if so, how can I apply convolution to the knot spans of a knot vector to produce the same B-spline basis that we'd get by using the Cox-de Boor formula?

Comment: I'd guess that the convolution formula works only in the case of equally-spaced knots. Just a guess, though. And, for this case, the algebra simplifies drastically, and I would think you could just prove by brute force that both processes produce the same functions.

Comment: Does this help:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114813/define-uniform-b-spline-basis-functions-via-continuous-convolution?rq=1