# Is it possible to rewrite the B-Spline Basis functions nonrecusively

Tags: recursion, spline, desmos

B-Splines have a recursively-defined basis function $N_{i,j}(t)$ as shown here:
$$
\newcommand{\defeq}{:=}
N_{i,j}(t)\defeq\frac{t-t_i}{t_{i+j}-t_i}N_{i,j-1}(t)\frac{t_{i+j+1}-t}{t_{i+j+1}-t_{i+1}}N_{i+1,j-1}(t)
$$
I would like to re-implement this in an engine that doesn't support recursion (Desmos). Is there a way to rewrite this (potentially using sums?)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a given degree, you can obviously just combine the recursion steps to get a closed-form expression. For common degrees (2 or 3) this is not too bad, but it gets nastier after that.

And you don’t really need recursion (in the sense of functions calling themselves), anyway — you can just use a loop.

There are definitions of b-spline basis functions that use divided differences, or convolutions, but I don’t think those would be very helpful. See (for example) Carl deBoor’s book entitled “A Practical Guide to Splines”.

For simple examples, see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114813/define-uniform-b-spline-basis-functions-via-continuous-convolution?rq=1).

Comment: Care to show the definitions that use divided differences or convolutions? I haven't found them anywhere. 

I'm looking for a generic definition for any degree.

Comment: Added a reference

Comment: That book has nothing to do with b-splines. It's very interesting, but not what I'm looking for. B-Splines $\in$ Splines, Splines $\neq _{\kern-.1em n}$ B-Splines.

Comment: Interesting that you think that, since deBoor has been one of the main proponents of b-splines, over the years. The deBoor-Cox algorithm for evaluating b-splines is even named after him. And, in fact, one of the main results of the theory is that *every* spline is a b-spline.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm

Comment: Okay, that's my bad. I'm sorry. Thank you, I'll look more at that book now.